# PHP Form with Delete Button

Tags: php

Hello i am working on a project for my P.H.P Programming Class. And the book that we use is Murach's PHP and MYSQL. And for our project 6-1 the folder we are given is called tech_support. I will show you a screenshot of what i am working on. I currently use phpmyadmin and localhost to use for this project because that is server we use.

For some reason when i go to click on the delete button for the table in the product manager folder it will not delete it will just show a blank page. But now when i go to the product_manager/index.php page it doesnt show the table instead it gives me an error.

**Fatal error: Cannot redeclare get_products() (previously declared in C:\xampp\htdocs\tech_support\model\product_db.php:3) in C:\xampp\htdocs\tech_support\model\product_db.php on line 7**

And when i go to view the page i am working with in dreamweaver or notepad all it showes on line 7 is a closing curly bracket. I just dont understand why its saying that?? I can also show you my two codes that i have i have few pages in my product manager folder they are product_db.php, delete_product.php, add_product.php product_list.php. These are folders i am working with right now.

**product_list.php code**

```
    <?php include '../view/header.php'; ?>
<?php require ('../model/product_db.php');?>
<div id="main">

    <h1>Product List</h1>

    <div id="content">
        <!-- display a table of products -->
        <h2><?php echo $category_name; ?></h2>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Code</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Version</th>
                <th>Release Date</th>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>

            <?php foreach ($products as $product) : ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $product['productCode']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $product['name']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $product['version']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $product['releaseDate']; ?></td>
                <td><form action="." method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="action"
                           value="delete_product" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="product_code"
                           value="<?php echo $product['productCode']; ?>" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
                </form></td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </table>
        <p><a href="add_product.php">Add Product</a></p>
    </div>

</div>
<?php include '../view/footer.php'; ?>

**product_db.php code**
```

**product_db.php**

```
    <?php
function get_products() {
    global $db;
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM  products';
    $products = $db->query($query);
    return $products;
}

function get_product($product_id) {
    global $db;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM  products
              WHERE productID = '$product_id'";
    $product = $db->query($query);
    $product = $product->fetch();
    return $product;
}

function delete_product($product_code) {
    global $db;
    $query = "DELETE FROM products
              WHERE productCode = '$product_code'";
    $db->exec($query);
}

function add_product($code, $name, $version, $releasedate) {
    global $db;
    $query = "INSERT INTO products
                 (code, name, version, releasedate)
              VALUES
                 ('$code', '$name', '$version', '$releasedate')";
    $db->exec($query);
}
?>
```

**delete_product.php code**

```
<?php
// Get IDs
$product_id = $_POST['productID'];

// Delete the product from the database
require_once('database.php');
$query = "DELETE FROM products
          WHERE productID = '$product_id'";
$db->exec($query);

// display the Product List page
include('product_list.php');
?>
```

Okay so the table name for the table is called **products** in tech_support phpmyadmin database. Here are the screenshots of what it looks like so far i have been staring and trying to figure out this code and its just starting to fustrate me.

Comment: Do you have try to change the name of get_product() ? Some your code are vulnerable at sql injection

Comment: For the `get_products()` error try declaring it as a `class` instead of a set of `functions`, then initialize your class and make calls to the associated `functions`.

Comment: well the thing is the way the coding is is from a previous exercise file that we did in class and some of the coding is similar to that. so what i did was use their coding but did some editing to work with the tech_support project but all the functions is what we use or are suppose to use for the project. so i am not sure how the class could work no we have to have both get_product() and get_products() because the teacher has that code also. i know its so confusing >.>

Comment: What does this question have to do with the Java programming language? I see no Java code, only the [tag:java] tag.

Comment: Java tag removed. Please don't use tags in a misleading way. That will only antagonize folks.

Comment: i am sorry about that i meant to put in php and mysql once again my apologies

Answer (score 0):

**Issue 1** - `"it will not delete it will just show a blank page"`

This will be caused by -

(1) your form does not have a valid `action`. (unless you are disabling the submit, and it is being done by a java OR javascript/jQuery/Ajax script in your `'../view/header.php'` file that you did not include.) This will post to an unknown/blank page.

```
<form action="." method="post">
```

(2) your `<input type="hidden">` is `name="product_code"` with `value="<?php echo $product['productCode']; ?>"`

```
<input type="hidden" name="product_code" value="<?php echo $product['productCode']; ?>" />
```

but in `delete_product.php` you are using `$product_id = $_POST['productID'];` and `WHERE productID = '$product_id'";`

```
$product_id = $_POST['productID'];
....
$query = "DELETE FROM products
      WHERE productID = '$product_id'";
```

Also, why are you re-writing you `DELETE` query? You should be using your function -

```
// Get IDs
$product_code = $_POST['product_code'];  // see final comment about SQL Injection

// Delete the product from the database
delete_product($product_code);
```

---

**Issue 2** - `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare get_products() (previously declared...`

This is an educated guess, without seeing your page layout/structure for `product_manager/index.php`.

If in `product_manager/index.php` you are including both of these files -

```
include('product_list.php');
include('delete_product.php');
```

You `product_manager/index.php` will essentially be-

```
include('product_list.php');
    |-> include '../view/header.php';  
    |-> require ('../model/product_db.php');
include('delete_product.php');
      |-> include('product_list.php');
              |-> include '../view/header.php';  
              |-> require ('../model/product_db.php');
```

Your `**Fatal error:**...` will be caused by including `product_db.php` twice, which you will be redeclaring your functions, and so it will fatal error out after the 1st redeclare (`get_products()`).

---

Note that your `functions/queries` in `product_list.php` & `delete_product.php` are vulnerable to SQL Injection. Please read -
[Best way to prevent SQL Injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection)